# Add 6 hours to current time and display to page

Tags: javascript, time

So, I'm trying to add some labels to a graph, and I want to add them to 6, 12, 18, and 24 hours on the horizontal axis.

I want to write these times in a "hh:mm" format (23:10, 05:10, 11:10, and 17:10 for example) for the local (computer) timezone?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: If your problem is the formatting see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645994/node-js-how-to-format-a-date-string-in-utc/10647272#10647272

Answer (score 41, accepted):

based on [How to add 30 minutes to a JavaScript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)

```
var d1 = new Date ();
var d2 = new Date ( d1 );
d2.setHours ( d1.getHours() + 6 );
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date will show how to manipulate Date objects.

added your code with some fixes.
edited to add second document.write

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var timer = 24; 
var d1 = new Date(); 
var d2 = new Date();
d1.setHours(+d2.getHours()+(timer/4) ); 
d1.setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes()); 
document.write(d1.toTimeString("hh:mm"));
document.write(d1.getHours()+":"+d1.getMinutes());
</script>
```

Comment: When I use this, I get an uncaught exception.  Here's my code:                                  <script type="text/javascript">
                                  var timer = 24;
                                  var d1 = new Date();
                                    d1.setHours(+d1.getHours()+(timer/4) );
                                    d1.setMinutes(now);
                                    document.write(d1.toTimeString("hh:mm"));​


Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: when i copied your code there was a strange character after the last semi-colon. also, where are you defining `now`? did you mean [Date.now()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679974%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) because that returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: As a final question, the output of that string is: 18:45:12 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)  how do I get rid of everything after the 18:45?

Comment: `document.write(d1.getHours()+":"+d1.getMinutes());`

Comment: There's an error in your code. it should be var d1 = new Date (), d2 = new Date ( d1 ); You can't define a var after a comma.

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
var today = new Date();
alert(today);
today.setHours(today.getHours()+6);
alert(today);
today.setHours(today.getHours()+6);
alert(today);
today.setHours(today.getHours()+6);
alert(today);
today.setHours(today.getHours()+6);
alert(today);
```

Comment: So... this works with alerts, but not with document.write,  why would that be?

Comment: i didn't try with document.write.

Answer (score 4):

```
var MILLISECS_PER_HOUR = 60 /* min/hour */ * 60 /* sec/min */ * 1000 /* ms/s */;

function sixHoursLater(d) {
  return new Date(+d + 6*MILLISECS_PER_HOUR);
}
```

The numeric value of a date is milliseconds per epoch, so you can just add a number of milliseconds to it to get an updated numeric value.

The `+` prefix operator converts the date to its numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
function getDateString(addT){
    var time = new Date();
    time.setHours(time.getHours() + addT );
    return ((time.getHours()<10)?"0":"")+time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes();
}
```

Then just use it pop out the data on the graph where you want?

ie:

```
for (i=0;i<=24;i+=6){
    yourbox.innerHTML = '<p>'+getDateString(i)+'</p>'; 
}
```

or somesuch;

Answer (score 2):

I like to do this like that

```
new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() + 6))
```

or

```
new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() + 6)).toString()
```