# Datetime Picker schedule time to 8 hrs from current time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

I'm using [DateTimePicker jQuery plugin by XDSoft](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/), please check below image

[image: Screenshot]

My requirement is that, if i selected current date,(9th Nov, 2015) then the time from time picker should show 6hrs add to current time...

I mean, in above image current Date is selected... and current time is 12.00 but i want that 12.00 & above time should be disable..

How can we do that..??

Comment: I'm positively sure that it depends on what datepicker you are using...

Comment: i m using normally jquery datepicker from http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on XDSoft DateTimePicker documentation, here's what can be done:

```
var logic = function( currentDateTime ){

    var d1 = new Date();

    // Check that it's today, so we need to restrict time chooser
    if (currentDateTime.getDate() == d1.getDate() && currentDateTime.getMonth() == d1.getMonth())
    {
        // Adding six hours
        d1.setHours ( d1.getHours() + 6 );    

        // Creating 'HH:MM' string
        var defaultTime = (d1.getHours() < 10 ? "0" : "") + d1.getHours() + ":" + (d1.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" : "") + d1.getMinutes();

        // Enforce time restriction
        // ('this' is jquery datetimepicker object)
        this.setOptions({
            minTime : defaultTime,
            defaultTime : defaultTime
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // Lift time restriction if selected day is not today
        this.setOptions({
            minTime : false,
            defaultTime : false
        });
    }
};

// Initiate datepicker with custom logic
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    onChangeDateTime:logic,
    onShow:logic
});
```

---

Adding 6 hours solution based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13034220/2715393

Comment: just want to know, is it possible to show time in textbox on timer click.. because now when we click on date it show current time with date in textbox..??

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In the example above when you click on timer, selected date and time are then set in the input box, from which datetimepicker had been called.

Comment: i mean to say that, if current time is 18.02 and i click on current date, in the input box its show current date & current time, instead of  current date & time + 6 hrs..

Comment: @DhawalMhatre  Could you look at this question I asked similar to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265386/add-6-hours-if-outside-of-business-hours-to-datetimepicker minTime is only working of '0'