# Convert today date in other format

Tags: javascript, date

How in JS can I convert this:

```
var today = "2014-8-20";
```

to this:

```
var today = "Wed Aug 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)";
```

Comment: Whip out your keyboard and type the second one instead?

Comment: Did you even try looking at existing answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var today = "2014-8-20";
today = new Date(today).toString();
//Wed Aug 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)";
```

But if you need anything more sophisticated I recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Hahaha, too easy! :)

Comment: Support for less-common formats will vary between browsers. V8/Chrome seems fine with `YYYY-M-DD`, but Firefox gives `"Invalid Date"`.

Answer (score 0):

var today = "2014-8-20"; console.log(new Date(today));