# Convert a date from one format to another javascript

Tags: javascript, date, format

For some reason I am having an issue using getDate() and getFullYear() functions.

I have the following input:
    Fri Jul 01 2005 00:00:00 GMT-0400

I am getting an error in an Oracle product stating "Cannot find function getDate in Object Fri Jul 01 2005 00:00:00 GMT-0400"

I believe i need to convert the above format to mm/dd/yyyy for the getDate function to work. how can I convert to the format I want ?

Thanks in Advance.

here is my Code:

```
var bftStartDt = input1[0];
var bftEndDt = input1[4];
var aDt = new Date("12/01/2099");
var strtDt = new Date(bftStartDt);
var endDt = new Date(bftEndDt);
var flag1 = 0; //false
var flag2 = 0; //false
var flag3 = 0; //false
var flag4 = 0; // false
var dblDelta = 0
var endDtDay = 0;
var bftEndDtMnth = 0;
var endDtYr = 0;
var holdEndMnth = 0;
var endDt_Sub = "";
var endDtOutput = "";

if (endDt <= strtDt){
  flag1 = 1; // true
}

if (endDt > aDt){
   endDt = aDt;
   flag3 = 1;
  }

// Set end date to the last payment period before '12/1/2099'
if (flag1 === 1 || flag2 === 1 || flag3 === 1){

if (endDt - aDt != 0) { // check they are equal/same
  if (pmtFreq === 1){
     dblDelta = 1;
  }else if (pmtFreq === 2){
     dblDelta = 3;
  }else if (pmtFreq === 3){
     dblDelta = 6;
  }else if (pmtFreq === 4){
     dblDelta = 12;
  }
  // get day of the month & full year
  endDtDay = endDt.getDate();
  endDtYr = endDt.getFullYear();
  holdEndMnth = parseInt(endDt.getMonth() + 1) - dblDelta;

  // Check for negative month
  if (holdEndMnth < 1){
     holdEndMnth = holdEndMnth + 12;
     endDtYr = parseInt(endDt.toDateString().substr(11,14)) - 1;
     bftEndDtMnth = holdEndMnth;
  }else {
     bftEndDtMnth = holdEndMnth;
  }
  flag4 = 1;
 }else {
    //do nothing - output original endDt
    flag4 = 0;
 }
}else {
  //do nothing - output original endDt
 flag4 = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello sir, I don't understand your question , you said about JS date formatting but also said about Oracle , you are trying to pass the date to DB or something like that ??  maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript

Comment: No I am not passing anything to DB. i am using an Oracle product that allows me to script. Scripting is done in JS. It seems like getDate is not able to get the day based on the format. I think i need to change the format to mm/dd/yyyy for it to work.

Comment: could you tell what are the contents of input1[..] array ?? because the value will be passed on Date object .., is it Fri Jul 01 2005 00:00:00 GMT-0400 which means that you declare something like this new Date ("Fri Jul 01 2005 00:00:00 GMT-0400") ??