# description of $('#hourly').html(hourly)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code :

```
$('#location').html(location);
$('#temperature').append(temperature);
$('#temperature').attr("value", temperature);
$('#weather').html(weather);
$('#summary').html(summary);
$('#hourly').html(hourly);
```

I want make description for every word show in html  . like this `$('#hourly').html(hourly) + 'next 24 hours'` 
but when make like that not showing describe  next 24 hours .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some additional text, you need to use the same `html` function to add it:

```
$('#hourly').html(hourly + 'next 24 hours');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this: `$('#location').html(location);` looks for a variable called "location" so it can put its contents in an HTML element with the `id="location"` attribute.

If you type it like this: `$('#location').html('location');` the string "location" will be inserted in the element with the "location" id.

You can combine any number of variables, strings and functions being executed as parameters: `$('#location').html('Current Location: ' + location);` (assuming the "location" variable contains the data for the current location).

If you want to display the current time, there is a post about the Date(); function that can help you do that: [Current time formatting with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript)