# How to change date format from fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have this function:

**CODE JS:**

```
function addEditEvent(state, event, start, end) {
    if (state == "select") {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        var completeD = start.format("YYYY/MM/DD H:mm");
        var dt = new Date(completeD);
        $("#time").val(dt);
        //some code JS
    }
}
```

after running this code I get the following format:

```
Tue Feb 09 2016 10:30:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
```

I just want to keep here time and remain so

```
10:30:00
```

how to do so to stay that way?
It can easily change the date format and remain only time?

**EDIT:**

```
 var completeD = start.format("HH:mm:ss");
 var dt = new Date(completeD);
 $("#time").val(dt);
```

Unfortunately I get this error message `"invalid data"`

Comment: `start.format("H:mm");` try this

Comment: Possible it is duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript

Comment: @Maris I also edited my previous answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/) date format as fullcalendar use moment for date related stuff

Try this

```
  $("#time").val(start.format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

No need to use date object. You can directly set from moment object to your input field.

Comment: i think OP wants time only

Comment: Now work but all the same format  Tue Feb 09 2016 10:30:00 GMT+0200 (EET)

Comment: I want to display just hours..not MM not DD not YYYY

Comment: I have edited my answer again with HH:mm:ss format. Is it ok for you? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102990/discussion-between-chintan-mirani-and-marius).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
  var completeD = start.format("HH:mm:ss");
```