# Convert HH:MM input value to javascript valid date

Tags: javascript

I have an input value of a time specifically formatted `HH:MM` is there way I can convert it to a javascript valid date for example:

Time is: `10:20`

Valid javascript time would be: `Mon Aug 15 2016 10:20:00`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript please check this, it may helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var timeString = "10:20:51";

var timeStringArray = timeString.split(':');
var hours = timeStringArray[0];
var minutes = timeStringArray[1];
var seconds = timeStringArray[2];

var now = new Date();
now.setHours(hours);
now.setMinutes(minutes);
now.setSeconds(seconds);

console.log(now);
```

This just changes the hours/minutes component of the current time though

Comment: need to set Seconds too

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I'll just recode it so it will fit to my code.