# How to get current time with format example: 2018-01-22T11:48:39.396000Z in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a very basic question to ask but I can't find it in Google and Stack Overflow too.

How to get current time with format example: 2018-01-22T11:48:39.396000Z in JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Current time formatting with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

`new Date().toISOString() // "2018-03-02T03:46:26.814Z"`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually this is thing I need.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

```
 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.toLocaleString([], { hour12: true });
```