# time reloads every 5 seconds setinterval jquery

Tags: jquery

I want a div reloads its time showed every 5 seconds.

**JQUERY** This is an approach...

```
time_showed1=$.now();//how to format in segs, then mins, then hours..

setInterval(function() { time_showed=time_showed1;}, 5000);

("#container").append("updated at:"+time_showed+" time");
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="container"></div>
```

I tried this as well but nothing

```
myFunction = function() { 

        time_showed=$.now();
    };


      setInterval(myFunction(), 2000);
```

Comment: You need to update  the HTML *inside* your setInterval callback if you want the HTML to update every time the interval is called

Comment: Move your append inside the set interval function.  you may also want to use .text instead of append - otherwise you get a new line of text every 5 seconds

Comment: what if onlywant to update an `span` within `#container`. Because I dont want to reload the whole container

Comment: target the span in your selector then

Comment: @joe `$(".my-span").text("updated at:" + time_showed + " time");`

Comment: it make sense. let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() { 
    time_showed = time_showed1;
    ("#container").append("updated at:" + time_showed + " time");
}, 5000);
```

You need to set the time inside the function called by setInterval. And

```
myFunction = function() {     
    time_showed=$.now();
    ("#container").append("updated at:" + time_showed + " time");
};
setInterval(myFunction, 2000);
```

You need to pass a function to setInterval, you were passing the result.

Comment: @joe [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript) is a comprehensive answer.