# Angular: Convert UTC to local date time

Tags: angular

I want to convert 2018-04-03T06:08:08-05:00

to

MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm

How can i do this in Angular 4.x+ ?

Comment: use angular date pipes https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 1):

Same as vanilla javascript using Date using getHours(), getMinutes(), and so on. Here is a reference to a similar question that may be helpful.

[Current time formatting with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

In html:

```
<p>Formatted  Date: <b>{{ newdate | date:'MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm' }}</b> </p>
```

In component:

```
newdate = new Date('2018-04-03T06:08:08-05:00');
```

Output:

```
Formatted Date: 04.03.2018 22:29
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-pipe)

Comment: Hi 

`newdate = new Date('2019-08-31T17:01:00');
  fullDate = new Date('2019-08-31T17:01:00-05:00');`

converted to

`<p>Formatted Date: <b>{{ newdate | date:'h a' }}</b> 
Full Date with zone difference <b> {{fullDate | date: 'h a'}} </b> </p>`

output is : `Formatted Date: 5 PM Full Date with zone difference 3 PM` 

what is the difference in handling

Comment: @Krish, use moment js for handling your time zone

Answer (score 0):

you need to check this out : https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

as it says in the link you can declare a date in your component such as :

```
export class DatePipeComponent {
  today = Date.now();
}
```

and then convert it to ur desired format using pipe :

```
{{today | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z':'+0900'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

these all are the multiple way you can use timezone in angular:-

```
{{currentDate | date:'short':'UTC +9:30 / +10:30'}}
{{currentDate | date:'short':'GMT'}}
{{currentDate | date:'short':'-0600'}}
{{currentDate | date:'short':'UTC+4'}}
```

date formats are given below:-

```
medium: Sep 9, 2019, 12:35:54 PM
long: September 9, 2019 at 12:35:54 PM GMT+5
full: Tuesday, September 9, 2019 at 12:35:54 PM GMT+05:30
shortDate: 09/3/19
mediumDate: Sep 9, 2019
longDate: September 9, 2019
fullDate: Tuesday, September 9, 2019
shortTime: 12:35 PM
mediumTime: 12:35:54 PM
longTime: 12:35:54 PM GMT+5
fullTime: 12:35:54 PM GMT+05:30
```

these all are the different time zone example:-

```
Alpha Time Zone 'UTC+1'
Arabia Standard Time 'UTC+3'
Central Standard Time 'UTC-6'
China Standard Time 'UTC+8'
Delta Time Zone 'UTC+4'
Greenwich Mean Time 'UTC+0'
Gulf Standard Time 'UTC+4'
Hawaii Standard Time 'UTC-10'
India Standard Time 'UTC+4'
```