# Is there any angular pipe or method to get UTC CENTRAL TIME FOR US & CANADA?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I used below code but getting one hour delay. Is it good approach to add one hour to it?

```
 *todayISOString : any = new Date();

{{todayISOString | date:'h:mm:ss a': 'UTC-6'}}*
```

Actually I am looking for below time zone.
[Required Time Zone Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7W6O.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: Convert UTC to local date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634707/angular-convert-utc-to-local-date-time)

Comment: You can already find a solution. Possibly a duplicate question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634707/angular-convert-utc-to-local-date-time

Answer (score 0):

in angular you can use timezone time like this way

```
{{todayISOString | date:'short':'UTC +9:30 / +10:30'}}
{{todayISOString | date:'short':'GMT'}}
{{todayISOString | date:'short':'-0600'}}
{{todayISOString | date:'short':'UTC+4'}}
```

date formats are given below:-

```
medium: Sep 9, 2019, 12:35:54 PM
long: September 9, 2019 at 12:35:54 PM GMT+5
full: Tuesday, September 9, 2019 at 12:35:54 PM GMT+05:30
shortDate: 09/3/19
mediumDate: Sep 9, 2019
longDate: September 9, 2019
fullDate: Tuesday, September 9, 2019
shortTime: 12:35 PM
mediumTime: 12:35:54 PM
longTime: 12:35:54 PM GMT+5
fullTime: 12:35:54 PM GMT+05:30
```

these all are the different time zone example:-

```
Alpha Time Zone 'UTC+1'
Arabia Standard Time 'UTC+3'
Central Standard Time 'UTC-6'
China Standard Time 'UTC+8'
Delta Time Zone 'UTC+4'
Greenwich Mean Time 'UTC+0'
Gulf Standard Time 'UTC+4'
Hawaii Standard Time 'UTC-10'
India Standard Time 'UTC+4'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I used UTC-6 but getting one hour delay compared to Central US & CANADA Time Zone. Is there any approach?

Comment: did u tried in this way {{todayISOString | date:'short':'-0600'}}

Comment: Yeah I used {{todayISOString | date:'short':'-0600'}} but still 1 hour difference is there.

Comment: its because of daylight saving 1 hour showing less. its better to use moment.js libarary.

Comment: Thanks Miya Mohammed for the reply. I used angular CST pipe. It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Offsets are not time zones.

I'm not an expert on North American time zones, but as far as I can see on [timeanddate.com](https://timeanddate.com), both the US and Canada are currently observing the Central Daylight Time, which is at offset UTC -5. This is probably why an offset of -6 gives you a result which is one hour off from what you expect.

If you want your code to behave correctly on all days of the year, you should install a library with an actual time zone database, such as [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). If you specify the time zone of an actual location which your users are in (e.g. "America/Winnipeg"), you will be able to calculate the time actually observed in that location, taking into account daylight saving time and any future political changes that might cause the time zone to change.