# Add "am" or "pm" to Specific Time Format Dependent on Time of Day - Javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I have the following javaScript which is showing the time in hours and minutes.

Is there a way of having an "am" or "pm" next to the time, dependent on whether it's before or after midday?

```js
var t = new Date();
var time = document.getElementById("time");

time.textContent = t.getHours() + ":" + t.getMinutes();
```

```html
<h3 class="time-holder">Current UK time: <span id="time">12:00</span></h3>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Answer adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript).

```js
var d = new Date();
var hr = d.getHours();
var min = d.getMinutes();
if (min < 10) {
    min = "0" + min;
}
var ampm = "am";
if( hr > 12 ) {
    hr -= 12;
    ampm = "pm";
}


var time = document.getElementById("time");

time.textContent = hr + ":" + min + ampm;
```

```html
<h3 class="time-holder">Current UK time: <span id="time">12:00</span></h3>
```

Answer (score -1):

use the "toLocaleTimeString()" method instead of the "getHours()" and "getMinutes()"

for example:

```
var t = new Date();
var time = document.getElementById("time");

time.textContent = t.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
```

source:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaletimestring.asp