# Displaying date to month dd, yyyy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

given time_cancel = 2019-01-06T23:29:35.000Z, would like to format it to month dd, yyyy (in this example, it is January 06, 2019)

In the following code, I have to write 12 if else block to convert mm to month
i.e. in this case, is to convert 01 to January.

is there a better /faster way to convert time_cancel to format month dd, yyyy in Javascript or Typescript/es6/react. Thanks in advance!

```
let date = time_cancel.split("T")[0];
var dateArray = date.split("-"); 
var month;

// 12 if else code
if(dateArray[1]=='01') month='January';
else if(dateArray[1]=='02') month='February';
 ....
else if (dateArray[1]=='12') month='December;

var res=month+" "+dateArray[2]+", "+dateArray[0];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Current time formatting with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript)

Comment: Use the below package, you can do a lot of other manipulation on date and time. https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.toLocaleDateString()` can give you DD Month YYYY, but it doesn't let you customise the order. I would be very tempted to stick with this default behaviour, but you can chop it up if your really must. You still profit from the locale awareness and translations...

```js
const formattedDate = new Date("2019-01-06T23:29:35.000Z")
.toLocaleDateString({},
  {timeZone:"UTC",month:"long", day:"2-digit", year:"numeric"}
  )
  console.log(formattedDate)
const sp = formattedDate.split(' ')
console.log(`${sp[1]} ${sp[0]}, ${sp[2]}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make an array like

```
let months = ["January", "February", "March", /*etc*/];
```

Read about [getMonth()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp)

lets say you have a date `let date = new Date();`

Simply do `let m = date.getMonth()` and it will return values from `0 to 11`.

Then you can just say `months[m]` and you will get your desired date.

**Here is a JSFiddle**, feel free to edit the months in date to check it's validity.
http://jsfiddle.net/snqwg7vd/

Comment: but new Date() is returning current date and time, I'd like to just past the above previous time stamp in the function (not the current timesteamp)

Comment: just npm install moment and then import moment from 'moment' in React but it says module not found.

Comment: I just put `new Date();` to get an example date. If you already have a date, you can skip that part.

Comment: Tried the following code but it returns 0 but would like it to return January.
 time_cancel = 2019-01-06T23:29:35.000Z
 let month = new Date(time_cancel).getMonth();

Comment: Of course it returns 0, because it's January. I told you it returns values from 0 to 11, where 0 is January and 11 is December. Let me create a fiddle for you.

Comment: Check the JSFiddle and see what it returns now.

Comment: I don't like to be discouraging, but people have to stop creating arrays of months. There are enough in the world already.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function formatraw(date, format, utc) {

    let raw = new Date(date.split(" ").join("T"));

    let res = format.slice();

    const MMMM = ["\x00", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    const MMM = ["\x01", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    const dddd = ["\x02", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    const ddd = ["\x03", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

    function ii(i, len) {
        let s = i + "";
        len = len || 2;
        while (s.length < len) s = "0" + s;
        return s;
    }

    const y = utc ? raw.getUTCFullYear() : raw.getFullYear();
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])yyyy+/g, "$1" + y);
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])yy/g, "$1" + y.toString().substr(2, 2));
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])y/g, "$1" + y);

    const M = (utc ? raw.getUTCMonth() : raw.getMonth()) + 1;
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])MMMM+/g, "$1" + MMMM[0]);
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])MMM/g, "$1" + MMM[0]);
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])MM/g, "$1" + ii(M));
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])M/g, "$1" + M);

    const d = utc ? raw.getUTCraw() : raw.getDate();
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])dddd+/g, "$1" + dddd[0]);
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])ddd/g, "$1" + ddd[0]);
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])dd/g, "$1" + ii(d));
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])d/g, "$1" + d);

    const H = utc ? raw.getUTCHours() : raw.getHours();
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])HH+/g, "$1" + ii(H));
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])H/g, "$1" + H);

    const h = H > 12 ? H - 12 : H == 0 ? 12 : H;
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])hh+/g, "$1" + ii(h));
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])h/g, "$1" + h);

    const m = utc ? raw.getUTCMinutes() : raw.getMinutes();
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])mm+/g, "$1" + ii(m));
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])m/g, "$1" + m);

    const s = utc ? raw.getUTCSeconds() : raw.getSeconds();
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])ss+/g, "$1" + ii(s));
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])s/g, "$1" + s);

    let f = utc ? raw.getUTCMilliseconds() : raw.getMilliseconds();
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])fff+/g, "$1" + ii(f, 3));
    f = Math.round(f / 10);
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])ff/g, "$1" + ii(f));
    f = Math.round(f / 10);
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])f/g, "$1" + f);

    const T = H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\]){TT}/g, "$1" + T);
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\]){T}/g, "$1" + T.charAt(0));

    const t = T.toLowerCase();
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\]){tt}/g, "$1" + t);
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\]){t}/g, "$1" + t.charAt(0));

    let tz = -raw.getTimezoneOffset();
    let K = utc || !tz ? "Z" : tz > 0 ? "+" : "-";
    if (!utc) {
        tz = Math.abs(tz);
        let tzHrs = Math.floor(tz / 60);
        let tzMin = tz % 60;
        K += ii(tzHrs) + ":" + ii(tzMin);
    }
    
    res = res.replace(/(^|[^\\])K/g, "$1" + K);

    const day = (utc ? raw.getUTCDay() : raw.getDay()) + 1;
    res = res.replace(new RegExp(dddd[0], "g"), dddd[day]);
    res = res.replace(new RegExp(ddd[0], "g"), ddd[day]);

    res = res.replace(new RegExp(MMMM[0], "g"), MMMM[M]);
    res = res.replace(new RegExp(MMM[0], "g"), MMM[M]);

    res = res.replace(/\\(.)/g, "$1");

    return res;
}

console.log(formatraw("2019-01-06T23:29:35.000Z","MMMM dd, yyyy"))
```

Comment: it's changed by my self, this code have diff with source