# How to format date within array

Tags: javascript

I am constructing an array using .map, the output is as follows:

```
renderDataLabels = (labelArray) => {
  const res = Object.values(this.state.totalCalls);
  labelArray = res.map(label => {
    return label.date
  })
  console.log(labelArray);
  return labelArray
}
```

/// Output: ///

```
0: "2020-07-11"
1: "2020-07-12"
2: "2020-07-13"
3: "2020-07-14"
4: "2020-07-15"
5: "2020-07-16"
6: "2020-07-17"
7: "2020-07-18"
8: "2020-07-19"
9: "2020-07-20"
10: "2020-07-21"
```

How can I format the dates before returning the array so that they are formatted as Jul, XX 2020?

Comment: have you looked at momentjs? https://momentjs.com/

Comment: momentjs is what you're looking for.

Comment: [Displaying date to month dd, yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54231505) is more or less what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/). Using this library you can format date to any format required.

```
labelArray = res.map(label => {
    return moment(label.date).format('MMM, DD YYYY')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
renderDataLabels = (labelArray) => {
  const res = Object.values(this.state.totalCalls);
  labelArray = res.map(label => {
    const dateArray = label.date.split("-");
    const newDate = `${dateArray[1]}-${dateArray[2]}-${dateArray[0]}`;
    return newDate;
  })
  console.log(labelArray);
  return labelArray
}
```

instead of running to install momentjs, you can use this simply.

Comment: This doesn't meet his requirement. This will return 07 for the month not Jul

Comment: Yes your right, I didnt pay attention to the Jul month.

Answer (score 0):

I hope its helpful for you.

```js
const myDate = new Date('2020-04-18')

const dateFormated = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit' }) 
const [{ value: month },,{ value: day },,{ value: year }] = dateFormated .formatToParts( myDate ) 

console.log(`${month}, ${day} ${year}`)
```