# How to format time only using date-fns

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs, date-fns

Using date-fns, how it could be converted below piece of code using date-fns.
Basically, inputs are like, '01:40:20 PM' or '1:4:2 PM' or '3:2 PM' OR '03:2 PM'
And expected output to be consistent like, '03:02:00 PM' , in hh:mm:ss A format.

I could not find any particular method that allows format with time only.

Using moment js, it works fine as below:

```
 if (moment(timeString, ['h:m:s A', 'h:m A'], true).isValid()) {
    return moment(timeString, 'hh:mm:ss A').format('hh:mm:ss A');
  }
```

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript

Comment: Its using new Date() function. I just do have string for time values which can be 1 digit or 2 digits as above description.  If there is no any existing function then, might need to do string operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help convert any time-like string to the format you want.

```js
function getTimeFormat(time) {
let ta = time.trim().split(" ");
let slots = ta[0].split(":");
while(slots.length<3) slots.push(""); // make sure we have h:m:s slots
return slots.map( n => n.padStart(2, '0')).join(":") + " " + (ta.length>1 ? ta[1].trim().toUpperCase() : "");
}
console.log(getTimeFormat('3 pm'));  
console.log(getTimeFormat('3:1 pm'));  
console.log(getTimeFormat('3:15 pm'));
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems its not straight in date-fns utility.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me from:
"17:00:00.000" to "05:00 PM"

```
import { format, parse } from "date-fns";
```

...

```
const time = '17:00:00.000';
```

...

```
{format(parse(time.split(":", 2).join(":"), "HH:mm", new Date()), "hh:mm a")}
```

Answer (score 0):

const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(new Date());
const [timeValue, setTimeValue] = React.useState(format(selected, 'HH:mm'));

In the second line, format(selected, 'HH:mm') will get the value of hours:minutes from Date.

This is the easiest way.