# Javscript idiomatic way to extract local clock time (HH:MM:SS) form the Javascript Date

Tags: javascript

What is the idiomatic way to extract the local clock time from a Date Object. I can do string split like this but it does not look idiomatic to me

```
> date = new Date()
2022-06-13T04:37:50.074Z
> date.toString()
'Sun Jun 12 2022 21:37:50 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)'
> date.toString().split('T')[0].split(' ')[4]
'21:37:50'
```

Comment: From the linked question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46935603/3558960) is what I would currently consider to be the most idiomatic approach.

Comment: This is correct. Very sorry for posting noise question like this