# Not able to split a string in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send a request to node server. The browser sends the date in mm/dd/yyyy format which is handled by server in the below manner.

```
    var endDate;
    if (req.query.endDate) {
        endDate = new Date(req.query.endDate);
    }
```

This **works just fine in chrome** and other browsers except IE.

**In IE11, it encodes the date to '?5?/?24?/?2017' from '5/24/2017' for some reason.**
To fix this I am trying to do this :

```
    var endDate;
    if (req.query.endDate) {
        endDate=req.query.endDate.toString().trim();
        endDate=endDate.toString().split('?').join('');
        console.log('Log',endDate);
        endDate = new Date(endDate);
    }
```

Expected result is '5/24/2017' But it does not work.

When i see the split('?') for '?5?/?24?/?2017' in the logs it shows ['?5?/?24?/?2017'] as the result. Why is it not splitting the string?

Am I doing Anything wrong? 
Node version : 4.3.2(using NVM)
[image: Code]

[image: Error]

[image: Code]

Comment: This sounds more like an issue from the browser side, not the server side. You should probably focus on the code you are using to send the request to your application, rather than the node.js app

Comment: You are not able to split a string in Javascript not Node.js. Also be aware that these kind of date hack ups will most probably come back to bit you in the rear end at some point. Use a date library instead, i.e moment.js

Comment: Can't you use `replace('?', '')`?

Comment: Why not use the `replace` string method? `endDate.toString().replace('?','')`

Comment: why don't use `toISOString`.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219636/1960558

Comment: @slowdeath007 The code that I've written is in nodejs only. It is the IE which sends the malformed data in query parameters for which I am trying to find a fix

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Why can't you split at string in node.js? It is javascript.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm correcting the OP's assumption that Node.js has something to do with Javascript's `String` methods.

Comment: Why IE is modifying the parameter? @evolutionxbox replace is also not working.Tried that already. I've tried using regex also.

Comment: Also, when I check the type of req.query.endDate using 'typeof', it returns a string... Split should work in any case. Why isn't it working

Comment: @writeToBhuwan can you split a normal string? or use replace? are you getting any errors?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I just tried console.log('Log','?5?/?24?/?2017'.split('?').join('')); in my code and it worked fine. There is some problem with that particular string

Comment: Can you log `endDate.toString().replace`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It is giving back the same string. Plus I've updated the question with some screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case "?" could be not the question mark, assume, some UTF-8 symbol.

It can be used the date formatting itself:

```
var endDate = new Date(req.query.endDate);
endDate.toLocaleDateString()
```

or

```
var endDate = new Date(req.query.endDate);
(endDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + endDate.getDate() + "/" + endDate.getFullYear();
```

or regexp approach:

```
req.query.endDate.toString().match(/[0-9]+/g); // [month, date, year]
```

Comment: not working..  req.query.endDate.toLocaleDateString is not a function

Comment: Was it used: endDate = new Date(req.query.endDate); // changed the main comment

Comment: It throws an error on  new Date(req.query.endDate); Invalid date

Comment: Then, use regexp to retrieve numbers: req.query.endDate.toString().match(/[0-9]+/g)

Comment: it is returning  [ '5', '24', '2017' ]. And joined it to get the correct result. Please Put it as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer. :)