# ES6 - output date string to ISO format without any libraries

Tags: javascript, datetime, ecmascript-6

Almost like [Node.js - How to format a date string in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645994/), as 
the following is already the format that I want (*both* of them):

```js
var x = new Date();
console.log(x);
var u = x.toISOString();
console.log(u);
```

However, the output is in UTC time zone & format (as indicated by the trailing Z), whereas,

I just need it in the local time zone. How to do that?

I've tried `.toLocaleDateString()`, `toLocaleTimeString()`, `toLocaleFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`, `toString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`, etc, etc, but none is working. pls help. thx.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @guest271314, "_in the local time zone_", same format.

Comment: Is not `new Date()` the local time?

Comment: @guest271314, yes it is, the *problem* is the *output*

Comment: @guest271314 No, a date in js is an absolute timestamp.

Comment: Is the expected output `"2018-01-23 04:19:07.641"`?

Comment: @Bergi, agree, that solves it.

Comment: `\`${d.getFullYear().toString().padStart(4, "0")}-${(d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0")}-${d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0")}T${d.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${d.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, "0")}.${d.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(3, "0")}\``

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function formatLocal(d) {

  // tzo is minutes, and signed opposite of the
  // usual -06:00 or +03:00 format you're used to
  const tzo = d.getTimezoneOffset()

  // get hours offset
  let tzH = Math.floor(Math.abs(tzo / 60))

  // get minutes offset
  let tzM = tzo % 60

  // pad and negate accordingly
  tzH = (tzH < 10) ? `0${tzH}` : tzH
  tzH = (tzo > 0)  ? `-${tzH}` : tzH
  tzM = (tzM < 10) ? `0${tzM}` : tzM

  // replace Z with timezone offset
  return d.toISOString().replace('Z', `${tzH}:${tzM}`)
}
```

Comment: thanks Ben, I don't care about the timezone offset, so the answer from @Bergi's link works for me well.