# Date format changes strangely

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

They're pretty stored in the database.

But when i take it from the node and sprinkle it into json, it changes into this format.

`YY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss` -> `YY-mm-ddThh:ii:ss,000Z`,

Why does it happen and How can i fix it?

Comment: It happens because it is converted to Javascript's native Date and then to string in the JSON. You can manually change the format using a library like moment.

Answer (score 2):

It is getting converted to a date object and when you stringify the javascript object it will call the date.toISOString() format, take a look at this:
[Node.js - How to format a date string in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645994/node-js-how-to-format-a-date-string-in-utc)

If you post some code we can help you.