# How to convert a date to yyyy-mm-dd in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a node.js application, I used Typescript to build my server, now I need to format dates posted to my server to yyyy-mm-dd format. I could do it in Javascript by using Moment.js but as I used Typescript, I could not figure it out how to convert a date string to yyyy-mm-dd so I can post data to database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a UTC date as a \`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss\` string using NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645994/how-to-format-a-utc-date-as-a-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-string-using-nodejs)

Comment: You should be able to use moment in type script.. Just use `Import * as moment from 'moment'` instead of require.

Comment: could you provide a simple code, because I tried it did not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class name it dateformater.ts or whatever you like

```
export class Dateformater{
  formatDate(date){
    let pubdate = new Date(date).toISOString().
    replace(/T/, ' ').      // replace T with a space
    replace(/\..+/, '');
    return pubdate;
  }
 }
```

import it in your ts file where you call your db functions to insert data to database

```
   import {Dateformater} from '../../lib/dateformate/dateformat.formate';



 export class MyClass{
      private _dateformater = new Dateformater();

  async insertData(body):Promise<any>{
try{
     //console.log(this._dateformater.formatDate(body.publishdate));
    let pubdate = new Date(this._dateformater.formatDate(body.publishdate));

    const pool = await poolPromise;
    const request = await pool.request()
            .input('Title',TYPES.VarChar,body.title)
            .input('StatusID',TYPES.Int,body.StatusID)
            .input('Publishdate',TYPES.DateTime,pubdate)

            let dyQuery = `INSERT INTO Tablename
            (Title, TestID, Publishdate)
             VALUES 
            (@Title, @StatusID, @Publishdate)`;
            const result = await request.query(dyQuery);
    //const result = await request.query(CustomQuery);
    return result.rowsAffected;
}catch(err){
    this.logger.StartLogger().error(err);
}
}
}
```