# How to format DateTime String

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am trying to format my DateTime string I retrieve from an API 
from YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM: SS +08:00
to DD-MM-YY HH: MM

```
retrieveApiData(res) {
    this.time = this.time.items[0].timestamp;
    console.log(this.time);
    document.getElementById("time").textContent = "Time Taken: " + this.time;
}
```

My console log result: `2020-06-17T11:20:00+08:00`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Take a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219636/615274

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this way

```
var date = new Date(this.time);
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' }));
```

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' }).replace(/\//g,'-'));
```