# How to get date of today + 00:00:00 in time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I try to get today date + time(00:00:00)

So I do it like this:

```
 const startDate = DateTime.fromISO(params.start)
                  .startOf('day')
                  .toFormat('yyyy-LL-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

But If I do a `console.log()`:

```
 console.log('startData',  startDate);
```

I get an **error**:

> line-chart.service.ts:22 startData Invalid DateTime

So what I have to change?

So I want it to use in here:

```
return this.sensorNodeService.cameraDataInInterval(
      16,
     startDate,
      '2021-01-20 23:59:59',
      '1'
    );
```

Comment: What is `DateTime`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It seems to be [this library](https://github.com/eakoriakin/date-time-js), but we can't be sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let c = new Date(); // take the current time

c.setHours(0);
c.setMinutes(0);
c.setSeconds(0);

// prints the current day at 00:00:00 in your timezone
// in the format 2020-12-02 12:10:12
console.log(c.toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, ''));
```

Edit: To format the code in the right way, I used the answer from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645994/how-to-format-a-utc-date-as-a-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-string-using-nodejs).

Comment: oh, b ut it is with t and z. That is not what I mean

Comment: Sorry but what is t and z? Do you mean timezone?

Comment: And I am using angular. So this has to be the format: '2021-01-20 23:59:59'

Comment: Okay - you could do that using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645994/how-to-format-a-utc-date-as-a-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-string-using-nodejs). I will edit the answer.

Comment: But it has to begin of time with: 00:00:00

Comment: Why don't you just take a substring of the c.toISOString() and append " 00:00:00"?

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it, for both date/time; or time! :)

```js
function DateTime() {
    return (new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {year: 'numeric',month: 'numeric',day: 'numeric',hour: "numeric",minute: "numeric",second: "numeric",hour12: true}));
}
console.log(DateTime());

function Time() {
    return (new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
        hour: "numeric",
        minute: "numeric",
        second: "numeric",
        hour12: true
    }));
}
console.log(Time());
```

Comment: Explain... this is DateTime.

Comment: Right, but the OP's `DateTime` is probably from a library, and asks for help on what they're doing wrong, not on how to implement a such thing...

Comment: It is a different library, it's luxon.js fast searching would have suggested that within seconds. All answers here offer the native Date-Time feature in JS. What they're doing wrong is not utilizing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var todaydate = new Date();
var datetime = todaydate.getDate() + "/" +
  (todaydate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
  todaydate.getFullYear() + " " +
  +todaydate.getHours() + ":" +
  todaydate.getMinutes() + ":" +
  todaydate.getSeconds();
  
  
console.log(datetime);
```